# In Powershell when running 'Invoke-SSHCommand' it throws exception as parameter can't be found as 'SSHSession'

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I tried as below

```
$session = New-SSHSession -ComputerName $IPAddress -Credential $creds -AcceptKey
$result = Invoke-SSHCommand -SSHSession $session -Command "hostname"
```

The exception is as below

```
Invoke-SshCommand : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'SSHSession'.
+ $result = Invoke-SSHCommand -SSHSession $session -Command $updatepack ...
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-SshCommand], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Invoke-SshCommand
```

I checked the documentation for the command and it was as below

SYNTAX

```
Invoke-SshCommand [[-ComputerName] <String[]>] [-Command] <String> [-Quiet] [-InvokeOnAll] [<CommonParameters>]

Invoke-SshCommand [[-ComputerName] <String[]>] [-ScriptBlock] <ScriptBlock> [-Quiet] [-InvokeOnAll] [<CommonParameters>]
```

I have seen examples with parameter name as *SSHSession*, not sure whether the module i imported is wrong version or not.

Comment: You looking for this? https://github.com/darkoperator/Posh-SSH/blob/master/docs/Invoke-SSHCommand.md

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you already have the Posh-SSH module. (*Since you are not getting the Error : is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet*)

I would advice you to check the version of the POSH-SSH

```
Get-module -Name Posh-SSH
```

Or

```
Get-command Invoke-SSHCommand
```

[image]

Check the version of the Posh-SSH Version.

Try updating to the latest one if you are in a very old version.

```
Install-Module -Name Posh-SSH -RequiredVersion 2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

"Invoke-SSHCommand" is a cmdlet from the Powershell module called "PoshSSH". If you want to use it, you need to install it first.

Please check [this link](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Posh-SSH/2.1) for downloading / installing it.

Thanks.